# how to limit the network bandwidth direct adb?

Tags: android, adb

i testing my app direct adb, the device is connected to the network via WIFI, my test purpose is to download with the app some small file, but i need make some operations before the download finish.

There is some way to limit the network bandwidth direct adb?
for example limit the download rate to 10kbps

Comment: I don't think there is such an option. What you can do instead - use Android emulator. It can limit internet speed. Or use some proxy that limits the speed

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i must testing it in real device

Comment: `Or use some proxy that limits the speed`

Comment: Computer Share WIFI, and then connect the phone WIFI, computer settings speed WIFI